# duplicate a dataframe n times with a distinguishing variable

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'd like to grow `foo` by duplicating it `n` times and distinguish each copy of `foo` with a unique value of a new variable. If `n` is 3, I can do this verbosely by:

```r
library(tidyverse)

foo <- mtcars %>%
  filter(row_number() < 3)

# desired result
bind_rows(
  foo %>% mutate(key = "a"),
  foo %>% mutate(key = "b"),
  foo %>% mutate(key = "c")
)
#>   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb key
#> 1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   a
#> 2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   a
#> 3  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   b
#> 4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   b
#> 5  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   c
#> 6  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   c
```

I'm trying to find a more parsimonious way of doing this. Ideally I'd like to fit the solution into one line into which `foo` is passed with `%>%`.

My (failed) `purrr` attempt:

```r
foo %>%
  map_dfr(c("a", "b", "c"), ~ mutate(., key = .x))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your attempt to use `purrr`, doing `foo %>%` is not helping you because you don't need `foo` to be the first argument to `map_dfr`. Instead you can just do:

```
map_dfr(c("a", "b", "c"), ~ mutate(foo, key = .x))
```

If you  want to keep using a pipe, but stop `foo` being passed as the first argument, you can surround `map_dfr` with `{}`, which suppresses the automatic argument passing:

```
foo %>%
    { map_dfr(c("a", "b", "c"), function(x) { mutate(., key = x)}) }
```

(there may be more elegant ways to do this using different `magrittr` pipes, I mostly stick to `%>%`)

Comment: Ah. Any way I can suppress the first argument so I can pass `foo` into this somehow? Ideally I'd like to be able to drop this into a pipe in which `foo` is modified in various ways before and after doing this.

Comment: Cool, that works. There must be a pipe variant out there that doesn't have the first argument default and requires the dot to be placed explicitly.

Comment: @lost *"There must be a pipe variant out there that doesn't have the first argument default and requires the dot to be placed explicitly."* Why use a pipe in that case? You might as well use the function with explicit function arguments directly. The whole idea of piping is to pass the object on the LHS as the *first* argument of an expression/function on the RHS.

Answer (score 3):

We can use

```
library(tidyverse)
set_names(replicate(3, foo, simplify = FALSE), letters[1:3])  %>% 
               bind_rows(.id = 'key')
```

---

Or using `uncount`

```
uncount(foo, 3) %>% 
    mutate(key = rep(letters[1:3], each = 2))
```

---

Or with `unnest`

```
foo %>% 
   mutate(key = list(letters[1:3])) %>% 
   unnest
#  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb key
#1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   a
#2  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   b
#3  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   c
#4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   a
#5  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   b
#6  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   c
```